# How to add event listener with HTML template literals in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-listener, template-literals, html-templates

I have fetched some data from a URL and after that I have generated an HTML template for each item of received data using a `forEach` loop. After creating the HTML template for all the elements in response data I have assigned that to `document.body.innerHTML`. So it displays all elements with my HTML template.

The response has 30 objects and each object has a link (`clone_url`) with other information. I have generated HTML elements for those 30 objects using my HTML template, each has a name, profile Avatar and button to copy the specific link I have mentioned. I want to copy that link into the clipboard when user click the copy button.

Therefore, I want to add event listeners to the buttons. That is where I have been struggling because I have no idea how can I do that. Because I have to access each component and also I want to access related response object to get the link.

```js
const url = "https://api.github.com/users/shrutikapoor08/repos";

fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((users) => {
    console.log(users);
    let htmlText = "";
    users.forEach((i) => {
      htmlText += `
        <div class="repo-container">
        <p class="repo-title">${i.name}</p>
        <div class="repo-owner">
          <img
            src="${i.owner.avatar_url}"
            alt="avatar"
            class="avatar"
          />
          <a href="${i.owner.html_url}" class="repo-owner-username">${i.owner.login}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-container">
          <button class="repo-link-btn">Copy</button>
          <p class="tooltip">Link Coppied</p>
        </div>
      </div>
        `;
    });
    document.body.innerHTML = htmlText;
  });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.repo-container {
  background-color: rgb(255, 253, 251);
  border: 1px solid rgb(226, 226, 226);
  padding: 15px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.repo-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.repo-owner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.avatar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.repo-owner-username {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tooltip {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tooltip.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.link-container {
  display: flex;
}

.repo-link-btn {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the code I want to add with each button.

```
document.querySelector(".repo-link-btn").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const text = "";
  await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  document.querySelector(".tooltip").classList.add("active");
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector(".tooltip").classList.remove("active");
  }, 500);
});
```

`const text` should be equal to the response data objects URL. I have to access that data as well. What is the good practice for solving this problem?

Comment: [Event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). Add one listener to a parent element rather than lots of listeners to lots of elements. The events bubble up the DOM to the parent listener which catches them. You can then determine what action to take based on the information in the event.

Comment: @Andy But finally how can I access fetched response data to get that specific link to each and every component? Because inside the event listener I wanna access related response data. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use pure JavaScript you need to create loop and add event listener to all item like this:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".repo-link-btn")].forEach(function (item) {..}
```

And to find `clone_url` value you can set custom attribute like `data-cloneUrl="${i.clone_url}"` and then get it in click time: `e.target.getAttribute("data-cloneUrl");`

Note that this code is based on your html and pure JavaScript. There is more easy way by jQuery.

```js
        const url = "https://api.github.com/users/shrutikapoor08/repos";

        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((users) => {
                console.log(users);
                let htmlText = "";
                users.forEach((i) => {
                    htmlText += `
        <div class="repo-container">
        <p class="repo-title">${i.name}</p>
        <div class="repo-owner">
          <img
            src="${i.owner.avatar_url}"
            alt="avatar"
            class="avatar"
          />
          <a href="${i.owner.html_url}" class="repo-owner-username">${i.owner.login}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-container">
          <button class="repo-link-btn" data-cloneUrl="${i.clone_url}">Copy</button>
          <p class="tooltip">Link Coppied</p>
        </div>
      </div>
        `;
                });
                document.body.innerHTML = htmlText;

                [...document.querySelectorAll(".repo-link-btn")].forEach(function (item) {
                    item.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
                        const text = e.target.getAttribute("data-cloneUrl");
                        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
                        document.querySelector(".tooltip").classList.add("active");
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            document.querySelector(".tooltip").classList.remove("active");
                        }, 500);
                    });
                })
            });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap");

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        }

        .repo-container {
            background-color: rgb(255, 253, 251);
            border: 1px solid rgb(226, 226, 226);
            padding: 15px;
            width: 250px;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .repo-title {
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .repo-owner {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .avatar {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .repo-owner-username {
            font-size: 0.8rem;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .tooltip {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            width: fit-content;
            padding: 4px 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            font-size: 0.75rem;
            color: white;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

            .tooltip.active {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translateY(-10px);
            }

        .link-container {
            display: flex;
        }

        .repo-link-btn {
            margin: 10px 0px;
        }
```

Note that the snippet worked correctly But stack overflow snippet said `The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document`. So check the snippet in your computer.

Comment: @Kasun Has your problem been solved? let me know if there is a problem

Comment: Yes this is working!  But I don't understand how it works. I don't understand how it access response data object after `foreach` loop. `e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute("href");` How this thing access that url.

Comment: @Kasun Don't worry I explain for you. When you create an event the callback function parameter is event (say `e` here). and `e.target` is the target that you click on it. here is `button`. But your link is in the previous sibling of parent of button :) . I mean `div` with class `"repo-owner"`

Comment: @Kasun So first I get the parent of button that is div with `link-container` class and then I try to access `previousElementSibling` which is  div with `repo-owner` class. `e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling`

Comment: The final stage is get anchor tag from `repo-owner` class which is: `getElementsByTagName('a')` . I hope my explanation be clear for you

Comment: you said, `The link link is in the previous sibling of parent of button :) . I mean div with class "repo-owner"`. This is the thing I can't understand.  How it happens?

Comment: @Kasun the link is anchor tag with `repo-owner-username` class. that is put in div with `repo-container` class OK?

Comment: No its not the link. There is another link in response object called clone_link. That is what I wanna Access

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235747/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-kasun).